# How to update foreign key using entitystate.modified?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am new to MVC3 im trying to perform update function after edit which contents two foreign keys (BRANCH_ID,ITEM_MASTER_ID).
The problem im facing easy when branch_id or Item_master_id are not changed the row gets updated but if the foreigns keys change its throwing me an error:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Here is my model

```
public partial class MATERIAL
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ITEM_MASTER_ID { get; set; }
    public int BRANCH_MASTER_ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS_DETAILS { get; set; }

    public virtual BRANCH_MASTER BRANCH_MASTER { get; set; }
    public virtual ITEM_MASTER ITEM_MASTER { get; set; }
}
```

My edit function code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MATERIAL material)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(material).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        int tempid = material.ID;
        return RedirectToAction("listcontinue", new { id = tempid });

    }
    return View(material);
}
```

Help me in perform update even if my foreigns keys are changed.

here is my improved edit code

```
public ActionResult Edit(MATERIAL material)
    {
       var temp = Convert.ToString(material.ITEM_NAME);

        using (var context = new material_managementEntities())
        {
            var temp1 = (from cs in context.ITEM_MASTER
                         where cs.ITEM_NAME == temp
                         select cs.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            material.ITEM_MASTER_ID = temp1;
        }

        var temp2 = Convert.ToString(material.ITEMGROUP);

        using (var context = new material_managementEntities())
        {
            var temp3 = (from cs in context.ITEM_GROUP_MASTER
                         where cs.ITEM_GROUP_NAME == temp2
                         select cs.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            material.ITEM_MASTER_ITEM_GROUP_MASTER_ID = temp3;
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.MATERIALs.Attach(material);
            db.Entry(material).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            int tempid = material.ID;
            return RedirectToAction("listcontinue", new { id = tempid });

        }         
       return View(material);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to attach the object:

```
db.Materials.Attach(material);
db.Entry(material).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: NO chrfin even after attach its not working problem here is my foreign key changes and entity is not taking the new foreign key id

Comment: Strange - I use something similar here successfully. Can you show how you have set up the realtions in EF?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rPAbH.png here is my EF relationship diagram dont worry abt remaining columns i had removed for simplified question and many relations are one to many

Comment: Can you try to query the new referenced objects from the DB and set them to `BRANCH_MASTER` and `ITEM_MASTER` just to see if that would work?

Comment: please find my improved code of edit function above but still its not working also is there any other way to perform update

Comment: Not only the Id - get the whole object. I would like to see if he fails at the `null` there even if the ID is set. So not `select cs.ID` and `material.xxx_ID = id`, but `select cs` and `material.xxx = item`...

Comment: what do you mean by material.xxx = item, let me explain my problem i am getting all the values and ids to the controller when user press Update button, if the foreign key values are same as the one fetched during edit and displayed in view then the row gets updated but if the user select some other foreign key value then i am not able to save and my branch_id and item_name_id are shown up as dropdowns for the user, so if the user select another dropdown the key value changes and i am not able to save

Comment: i got the following error A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Comment: If there is any other way to update please let me know

Comment: I'm sorry I have no other idea how I could help you from here. As I already said the patter generally should work, as I use that too...

Comment: Its OK thanks for precious time, i will update using regular sql query

Answer (score 0):

I think in the context EF doesn't know about the foreign keys, I had to use an includes first before I update the foreign key:

```
db.Entry(team).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();

var updatedTeam = db.Teams.Include(x=> x.GameType).Where(x=> x.ID == team.ID).Single();
updatedTeam.GameType = db.GameTypes.Find(GameTypeId);
db.SaveChanges();
```